# Symfony - Is it possible to disable output escaping per module (or per template)?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to output some HTML in an XML template and Symfony's escaping method is messing it up. So I tried making a copy of settings.yml in the module's config folder, but it seems to be completely ignored. Is there an easy way to change the escaping_strategy and/or escaping_method settings per module or even per template?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While output escaping is turned on you still have access to the raw value through `$sf_data`.  For example, if the HTML you're trying to output was stored in a variable called html in your action:

```
$this->html = '<b>My HTML</b>';
```

You could get the unescaped value with this:

```
<?php echo $sf_data->getRaw('html') ?>
```

http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_activating_output_escaping

I don't believe there is a way to disable this functionality on a per-module basis.

Comment: Looks cool, didn't know about this.
I didn't understand the question like this and was about to answer, just for an object : $yourObject->getRawValue()->getProperty()
.. if it helps...

Comment: Julien: if he's trying to work out of a model object your solution would be perfect, you should post as an answer just in case.

Comment: Thanks Cryo, $sf_data->getRaw() did the trick. Julien, thanks for the info on how to use this from the model.

Answer (score 11):

getRaw only works if the variable is passed from the action. for variable within view use

```
sfOutputEscaperGetterDecorator::unescape($html)
```

Comment: I was looking to unescape some attribute, but unfortunately, attributes are not accessibles through $sf_data->getRaw(..). But your answer did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Just run into this problem today and i manage to solve it by setting `sfConfig::set('sf_escaping_strategy', false)` in my controller (either in `preExecute` method for all the actions in that module or in a specific action - `executeWhatever`).