# Disable escaping for admin generator list action?

Tags: escaping, symfony-1.4, admin-generator

I am configuring Symfony 1.4's admin generator for one of my data models ("Achievement"). The "Achievement" data model has a field ("url") that stores a URL to an external resource, and I would like this URL to render as a link in the admin generator list action. By default, the admin generator displays the link as plain text. I tried writing a function to decorate the URL with HTML, and trim the string if it is too long (added to "lib/model/doctrine/Achievement.class.php").

```
function getLink()
{
  $text = $this->getUrl();
  if(strlen($text) > 40)
  {
    $text = sprintf( "%s...%s", substr($text, 0, 20), substr($text, -20, 20) );
  }

  return sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $this->getUrl(), $text);
}
```

Unfortunately, in the admin generator list view the HTML is escaped, leaving a long ugly string. I cannot figure out how to disable escaping for this field.

If I change "ESC_SPECIALCHARS" to "ESC_RAW" in "apps/backend/config/settings.yml", the link renders correctly. Is there no finer-grained control of escaping for Symfony 1.4?

Answer (score 4):

You should not generate HTML in model. Instead create a [helper](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_helpers) function for that and make the field render as a [partial](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_helpers) and use the helper in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sfConfig::set('sf_escaping_strategy', false)` in your controller (actions.class.php) for `list` action. See my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180644/symfony-is-it-possible-to-disable-output-escaping-per-module-or-per-template/9396475#9396475) question.

But, like [1ed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1260260/1ed) said, you better make a helper for this, not write html code in your controller.